# VS Code Intellisense is extremely slow

Tags: typescript, performance, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using VSCode for more than a year and never faced this problem. The project I am working on is huge and VSCode is extremely slow when I am working on this project. 
I tried other projects and they work fine but what's strange is on the same project, a team of 10+ is working and most of them use VSCode but there seems no problem with their VSC.

I have to wait for like 2 minutes on first access to IntelliSense. So every time I open a file, I have to wait for like 2 to 3 minutes before I can see suggestions.

When I open Project, I get these messages, which is totally fine I guess. It's only for the first 10 seconds.
[image: Initialization]

After initialization is finish, it still keeps loading for the next 2 minutes.

[image: Loading]

**What I tried:**
I disabled all my extensions, reinstalled VScode, reinstall Windows (I'm using Windows 10), downgrade to previous version and even change my system but still, nothing works.

**System Specs:**
Core I5 (3rd Gen) with 16GB of Ram and SSD of 500GB

Comment: If you see this with all extensions disabled, please [file a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md). If possible, include a project that causes this

Comment: Try playing with your tsconfig/compiler options, I've had cases where some flags would slow down everything big time on a certain update (just remember to restart VS Code every time). A similar thing goes for linter rules, but you've already noted that you turned off extensions. Additionally, double-check your VS Code settings (both user and workspace), make sure that large directories such as node_modules are excluded from VS Code searching through them

Comment: There are so many settings. What should I search for in the command palette to stop VS code from searching node_modules?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I'm having this exact same problem on a brand new project, even after removing the node_modules folder. I'm not even using TypeScript in my project, however something is triggering it to load!

Answer (score 13):

Please delete the .vs folder in your project folder and restart the vscode, now the intellisense will work fine.

Comment: This worked for me - I deleted everything that wasn't in git

Comment: Is there something specific in the folder that should be deleted rather than the entire folder?

Comment: no .vs folder in the project, checked with `ls -la`

Comment: do you mean the .vscode folder? This hast just the launch.json and settings.json inside. I don't have a .vs folder

Answer (score 9):

**Solution 1**: First check if you have any extensions that's unresponsive. Navigate to **command palette** from **Settings**(bottom left corner), type in **'Show running extensions'** if you find any unresponsive extensions, delete it! *Reinstall it if you really need it*. An unresponsive extension can significantly slow down your IDE, as a result you will notice that adding/deleting/renaming a file, as well as intellisense taking forever.

**Solution 2**: Deleting the .vscode folder itself didn't work for me. I also had to do the following by navigating to **Preferences** **->** **Settings** **->** **Text Editor** **-> Suggestions** Up here I changed the delay for quick suggestions to 1 milliseconds. I ticked marked on **suggest:preview**. You might select other options there as per your requirements. Then restarting the VsCode fixed the problem

Comment: Solution 2 is what worked for me. I was also having this issue in Jupyter Notebookes but this helped that as well.

Answer (score 4):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580343/2021554 when you are working with larger files, typically those which exceed 3k lines and have nightly installed you'll see a slight improvement by disabling it.

In addition (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580343/2021554) excluding `node_modules` is also another performance gain overall which folks should indeed get into a habit of doing.

Excluding `node_modules` from the file explorer can be done by simply adding it file exclusions within workspace settings:

```json
    {
        "files.exclude": {
          "**/node_modules": true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

add a file to your project folder `.vscodeignore` and place `node_modules` inside it and be happy.

Comment: Not sure why you go downvoted here, though the answer could of been a little bit more detailed. This will indeed improve overall performance and users should get into a habit of excluding node_modules from the file explorer, but instead doing this via workspace settings `files.exclude` option.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, it is caused by this extendsion
[image]

removing it solved the issue

Comment: it seems like it looks for jsconfig/tsconfig file but when it doesn't find it, it gets stuck

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using the latest vs code version of v1.69 and it was very slow (~30 second delay on intellisense). I downgraded to v1.64.2 and everything is now quick. I also disabled auto update which is enabled by default.

Computer Spec:

- Chip: Apple M1 Pro
- RAM: 32 GB
- CPU Cores: 10 (8 performance and 2
  efficiency)
- Storage: 500GB

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32305854)

Answer (score 0):

There are many good suggestions but I have found that it is usually a combination of many things. From my experience here are some simple things you can do to instantly make it faster:

1. Add/Push everything go git that is not pushed.
2. Close your explorer side bar.
3. Close open files that you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case VScode was slowed down by a type-script file importing a large json file.
Like this:
`import mockWorkspace from 'src/assets/json/workspace-1.json;`

Answer (score -3):

I tried removing extensions, increasing size of memory in settings, reinstalling VSCODE.

What seemed to help me was committing to github. It seems odd, but ...

Comment: should be a comment